# Display an another application's window in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display another application's window that is running concurrently in my WPF application. Like a live display, I need to be able to see real-time changes to the window (in this case, Chrome's) even if it is hidden behind other windows while my WPF application is running. It's kind of like the image below:[image: Sample screenshot where the application just shows a Google Chrome window]

I understand I have to get the window's handle first, but how would I be able to display an external window like this? Is there a way I can use the Win32 API for this function?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into the `Frame` element (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.frame?view=netcore-3.1)).

```
<Frame Source="https://www.google.com"/>
```